# Create some new user profile properties from excel

Tags: powershell, user-profile

I have a CSV file with new properties that exist in the AD.

I want to add this properties to all user profiles, and set value from AD (the same property name is in the excel) and set description from another column of the excel.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If pnp powershell is an option you could use set-pnp user profile property (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpuserprofileproperty?view=sharepoint-PS) and combine it with import-csv (https://www.morgantechspace.com/2015/06/read-csv-file-in-powershell.html?m=1)

Comment: Then you should be able to use pnp powershell, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps